# Acces to a informations of GitHub private repositories

Tags: github

I would like to get my private repository's information with the GitHub API. Is there a solution with API key or something else ?
My api url:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{private repo}
```

I tried to accès with:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{private repo}?client_id=xxxx&client_secret=yyyy
```

and

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{private repo}&access_token=YYYY
```

But i have always a "Not Found" message

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication)?

Comment: yes of course, but i dont find to acces with a url like : https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPO&access_token=blabla

Comment: The link I provided links directly to the authentication section, which includes OAuth examples. Do these not work for you? Please [edit] your question and tell us what you've already tried and, specifically, how it didn't do what you want. See [ask].

Comment: oh sorry i'm confused. I dont see the OAuth2 key/secret section.. I'll go modify my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests i found this solution:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{private repo}?access_token=YYYY
```

I thought that the first get parameter was repos.